# can properties use array syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

can you use either `property` or `@property` to create something that uses array syntax? In code, this would look something like:

```
x = ExampleClass()
x.y[6] #x.y is a property, 6 is passed as an arg to getter function
```

thanks

Comment: No; `6` gets passed to the `__getitem__` of the object that `x.y.__get__` returns, not to the getter itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making `y` a container type:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...             return 2 * index
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a[3]
6
>>> class ExampleClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.y = A()
...
>>> x = ExampleClass()
>>> x.y[6]
12
```